# Javascript code in XsltListViewWebPart Give parsing error

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepoint-designer

I am working with XsltListViewWebPart, I add my custom xsl and it works good.This xsl contain an anchor tag like that

```
 <a>
       <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:attribute name="onclick"><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
 </a>
```

When I am trying  to complete my javascript code it gives me parsing error. Here is my code

```
 <a>
       <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:attribute name="onclick">OpenPopUpPage("/lists/news/dispform.aspx?isdlg=1&ID=<xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>");</xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
</a>
```

Can any one help me, Please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XML (and XSLT is XML) you need to escape any ampersand '&' as `'&amp;'` so try

```
 <a>
       <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:attribute name="onclick">OpenPopUpPage("/lists/news/dispform.aspx?isdlg=1&amp;ID=<xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>");</xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
</a>
```

or better yet use attribute value templates e.g.

```
<a title="{@Title}">
   onclick="OpenPopUpPage('/lists/news/dispform.aspx?isdlg=1&amp;ID={@ID}');">
   <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
</a>
```

as it makes the code shorter and easier to read.